# Large Message are not removed from message directory

Tags: activemq-artemis

Large message file is never get deleted from large message directory. The following code in Artemis is actually deleting the large message file from large message directory.  The following method is in class `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.AbstractSequentialFile`

```java
@Override
public final void delete() throws IOException, InterruptedException, ActiveMQException {
   if (isOpen()) {
      close();
   }

   try {
      Files.deleteIfExists(file.toPath()); //if file is not delete
   } catch (Throwable t) {
      logger.trace("Fine error while deleting file", t);
      ActiveMQJournalLogger.LOGGER.errorDeletingFile(this);
   }
}
```

In above code somehow if file is not deleted then this file is persist forever in large message directory. Can someone let me how I will solve this issue.

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who have this same question in the future. If not, please elaborate as to why. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a problem occurs when deleting the file then an `ERROR` message will be logged like:

```
Failed to delete file /path/to/file
```

You can use this information to determine which specific file was supposed to be deleted and then delete that file manually.

If no exception is logged (for whatever reason) and you want to get rid of the large message file on disk and that message isn't referenced in any queue on the broker then stop the broker, delete the file, and restart the broker.

Comment: If  there is no such error message then what to do in that case

Comment: Why was there no such error message? Was it because the corresponding log file was deleted or something or because there was no actual error deleting the file and it still represents a valid message in a queue?

Comment: There was no actual error message in the log file and the messages is not in the queue but file still exists in the large-messages folder

Comment: Are you sure the message hasn't been relocated to a dead-letter or expiry queue?

Comment: yes,  I am sure that message hasn't been relocated to dead-letter or expiry-queue